# SSRS image rendering issue with PDF

Tags: image, pdf, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm having an issue with an image in an SSRS report. It's a .PNG, 300dpi, 185 x 58. When I run the report through VS, it renders fine. The image object in the report is set to render at original size, so that all is fine. The problem arises when I save as PDF, everything goes all grainy and the colours also seem weird. That's kind of a problem, because these reports are meant to be printed.

Has anyone else experienced this issue, and if so how did you fix it?

What I have tried:

I've noticed that when I import the image it's sized to 4.87cm x 1.52cm, which according to this

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/48de91f9-1844-40c1-9614-5ead0b4b69a5/sql-server-reporting-services-faq?forum=sqlreportingservices

Makes sense, as that would make it 96dpi. When I open it in GIMP, the sizeis 1.56cm x 0.491 cm at 300DPI.

Comment: PNGs have issues... What happens if you use a JPEG instead?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out SSRS doesn't like PNGs... Converted to a JPG and the problems went away.